# PreferenceActivity Settings not Saved

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

EDIT: I tried this new code but it still seems they are reset. Can anyone tell me, and propose a solution to my settings being reset?

```
public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener{

    static SwitchPreference mucus_stamps;
    static SwitchPreference fertile_infertil;
    static SwitchPreference cervical_mucus;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * Populate the activity with the top-level headers.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","onBuildHeaders");
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);

    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows the preferences for the first header.
     */
    public static class Prefs1Fragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.notification_settings);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows the preferences for the second header.
     */
    public static class Prefs2Fragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.charting_settings);

            //findPreference("cervical_mucus").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
                    mucus_stamps = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("mucus_stamps");
                    fertile_infertil = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("fertile_infertil"); 
                    cervical_mucus = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("cervical_mucus"); 

                    cervical_mucus.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
                              new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                                     @Override
                                     public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                                         // string test w/o "==" usage.
                                         if (newValue.equals(false)) {
                                             Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","false");
                                             mucus_stamps.setChecked(false);
                                             fertile_infertil.setChecked(false);

                                         } else {
                                             Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","true");
                                             mucus_stamps.setChecked(true);
                                             fertile_infertil.setChecked(true);
                                         }

                                         // true instead of false so the new value gets kept
                                         return true;
                                     };
                              });


                      if(!cervical_mucus.isChecked()){
                             mucus_stamps.setSelectable(false);
                             mucus_stamps.setEnabled(false);

                             fertile_infertil.setSelectable(false);
                             fertile_infertil.setEnabled(false);
                         } else {
                             mucus_stamps.setSelectable(true);
                             mucus_stamps.setEnabled(true);

                             fertile_infertil.setSelectable(true);
                             fertile_infertil.setEnabled(true);
                         }
        }
    }

    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory 
         android:title="@string/pref_chart_profile" 
         android:textSize="20px">

        <SwitchPreference  
                android:title="@+string/pref_symptothermal"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_symptothermal_summary"
                android:key="symptothermal"
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:layout="@layout/pref_layout"/>

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:id="@+id/cervical_mucus"
                android:title="@+string/pref_cervical_mucus"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_cervical_mucus_summary"
                android:key="cervical_mucus"
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:layout="@layout/pref_layout" />    

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:id="@+id/mucus_stamps"
                android:title="@+string/pref_mucus_stamps"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_mucus_stamps_summary"
                android:key="mucus_stamps"
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:layout="@layout/pref_layout" />

        <SwitchPreference 
                android:id="@+id/fertile_infertil"
                android:title="@+string/pref_fertile_infertile"
                android:summary="@+string/pref_fertile_infertile_summary"
                android:key="fertile_infertil" 
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:layout="@layout/pref_layout" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want.

The value is saved(tested), but "selectable" is not a preference value. Therefore you have to set it when the preferencescreen is launched.

Do this:
Before your oncreate:

```
  SwitchPreference mucus_stamps;
```

Then above your findPreference("mucus_stamps")

```
  mucu_stamps = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("mucus_stamps");
```

Now, outside the onclicklistener, you can set it.

```
if(!mucus_stamps.isChecked()){
             mucus_stamps.setSelectable(false);
             mucus_stamps.setEnabled(false);
         }
```

(I added "setEnablet" to show you that you can disable it aswell, not just make it "non-selectable". Selectable only says that you can't click anything outside the "off/on" area to change it to on/off.)

Personally I prefer to do it like this:

```
    mucus_stamps = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("mucus_stamps");
    mucus_stamps.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
              new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                     @Override
                     public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                         //SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());




                         // string test w/o "==" usage.
                         if (newValue.equals(false)) {
                             mucus_stamps.setChecked(false);

                             mucus_stamps.setSelectable(false);
                         } else {
                             mucus_stamps.setChecked(true);
                         }

                         // true instead of false so the new value gets kept
                         return true;
                     };
              });


      if(!mucus_stamps.isChecked()){
             mucus_stamps.setSelectable(false);
             mucus_stamps.setEnabled(false);
         }
```

And, you don't need to implement OnPreferenceChangeListener when you do it the way you or I do. Not that it really matters.

:)

Comment: Made the edit but its still resetting when i got back to it. See my new code above